# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (no error message)

Tags: android, exception, gradle, build

Does anyone of you guys know this exception in Gradle build?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (no error message)
```

My project worked fine, until I implemented a Video player in a new activity that parses a MP4 file from the SD-Card. Then I got this exception. After that I updated Android Studio, I cleaned the project, I relocated it, I rebuilt it. This all didn´t solve the problem.
 Then I uncommented path calls for the case that this error happens because the generated build file path exceeds the windows max path length of 255 characters. This also didn´t work.

I would be thankful for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

I just changed my libraries to latest version and problem solved. for me it was 25.1.1 and i changed them to 25.2.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:[latest-version]'
compile 'com.android.support:design:[latest-version]'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[latest-version]'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:[latest-version]'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:[latest-version]'
```

Hope helps someone ;)

Comment: Unless the older libraries were sentient to cause you to update to the newer ones, I don't understand how the error just randomly appears when  it wasn't there all along.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Android Studio doesn't update the gradle version. You have to manually do it. In your project level build.gradle file, replace the gradle dependency with this version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I alreday have 2.1.2 in my Project Level build.gradle file. The Problem is still there ...

Comment: Sorry, coulnd't find any solutions. Maybe you can try to downgrade the gradle version and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I'm more or less sure it's not a code issue because the compiler recognizes no R directory anymore. I deleted my .gradle folder from my home directory restarted Android Studio and am installing all SDK components I could find now. I also changed the SDK I'm using to a lower version.... I´ll Keep you uptodate ... I´m in a wait and see mode right now  ;)

Comment: After I did the steps in my last comment above I got: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> -1

Comment: cleaning project AND/OR invalidate caches and restart? Try if they work. Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816499/android-studio-1-5-1-gradle-error-appmergedebugresources-failed

Comment: I reinstalled jdk and jre and don´t see the problem anymore. Instead I get  minSdk(API, N preview ) != deviceSdk(API 21) when trying to deploy on my smartphone. When I change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to the integer 21 in build.gradle minSdk(API, N preview ) != deviceSdk(API 21) is not solved. Any hints?

Comment: Problem solved by creating a new Project and migrating my .java and my .xml files manually from the old one.

Comment: Great. Maybe you should write everything you did in an answer and post it here. It'll be helpful to the people having similar issues.

Comment: As I already wrote I created a new Android project. Then added empty activities to the new App and copied the content of my .Java and my .XML files from the old project one by one in the activities of the new project.

Comment: I got automatically generated clean working new .gradle files and added the permissions that I need to my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Lesson of the day for me was: Never update Android Studio or change your SDK before finishing your project (at least until I understand all the things that one has to do manually after updating while still working on an App)

Answer (score -1):

If you guys now feeling tired after applying everything please do one thing

create a new project and shift all your code to that new project(if possible) but keep one thing in mind that start with classes and layout files and after every step run your code to check and which icons you need from drawables copy that into your project and run after every small step.

All in all i want to say you personally i have wasted so much time in this problem and this solution looks complex but this will take few hours but give 100% solution of your problem.

**Why we follow this long process?**
**many times what happened that we keep on writing the code and studio keep on accepting everything but at any day any random time(when R file regenerat) studio does not accept some of the things but you never came to know where you miss something that's why in some cases this approach might be look easy instead applying hit and try.**